# WPF. Как эффективно нарисовать большое количество фигур?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, wpf-canvas

Начал изучать создание WPF-приложений. На данный момент решаю задачу, связанную с методом кластеризации К-средних (k-means). Для решения данной задачи мне необходимо с помощью графических средств отобразить от 1000 до 100000 эллипсов на экране (значение выбирает пользователь). Я реализовал это с помощью `Canvas` и `Ellipse` следующим способом:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int clustersCount = Int32.Parse(label_ValueOfClustersCount.Content.ToString());
    int vectorsCount = Int32.Parse(label_ValueOfVectorsCount.Content.ToString());

    List<KMeansNS.Vector> vectors = KMeans.GenerateVectors(vectorsCount, 0, Convert.ToInt32(сanvas.Width), 
        0, Convert.ToInt32(сanvas.Height));

    foreach (KMeansNS.Vector vector in vectors)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        ellipse.Width = 4;
        ellipse.Height = 4;

        Point vectorLocation = new Point(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1]);
        Point newVectorLocation = CalcCoordinates(vectorLocation, ellipse);

        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, newVectorLocation.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, newVectorLocation.Y);

        сanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }

}

private Point CalcCoordinates(Point actualPoint, Shape shape)
{
    double newX = actualPoint.X - shape.Width/2;
    double newY = actualPoint.Y - shape.Height/2;

    return new Point(newX, newY);
}
```

Но при тестировании работы на количестве 100000 программа обрабатывает это все дело около 1 минуты. Есть ли способ значительно повысить эффективность данного кода? или может быть есть другой подход, более быстрый, для рисования фигур в WPF?

**UPD.** Нашел ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997891/how-to-improve-canvas-rendering-performance 
Сегодня уже нет времени разбираться. Завтра, возможно, вопрос отпадет.

Comment: Должны быть специальные библиотеки для построения таких типов графиков.

Comment: Вообще интересный вопрос. Зачем вам такое большое количество данных? Все равно пользователь визуально их не охватит.  Может есть смысл провести какую-нибудь обработку прежде чем отображать график?

Comment: Согласен, 100 000 объектов визуально пользователь не охватит. Но я ведь не разрабатываю программный продукт :) Это задание к лабораторной работе. В условии прописано, что количество входных векторов должно быть от 1 000 до 100 000, а кластеров от 2 до 20. Самый наглядный вариант работы алгоритма k-means получается при значениях 10 000 и 5 соответственно. Поэтому от работы с большим количеством объектов никуда не убежать :)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а можете показать как выглядит у вас сейчас результат при 100 000 объектах? Вы не против продолжить обсуждение в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) ? (мне кажется, там будет удобнее общаться)

Comment: @FoggyFinder к сожалению, с языком F# не знаком, поэтому реализацию Вашей идеи я не могу оценить. Саму идею понял. Но ведь для этого нужно пройти цикл со сложностью n^2. Для 100 000 это не будет критично?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko нет, там сложность будет меньше из-за использования HashSet. Это не единственный способ сокращения сложности, можно еще,например, использовать KD-деревья. Я написал на F#, так как я сейчас практически только его и использую. Но это не значит, что я не смогу переписать или объяснить как реализовать то или иное на C#. Главное не стесняйтесь спрашивать, если у вас возникнут какие-либо вопросы - не важно по C# или еще чему-то. Буду рад помочь

Comment: 100 000 не критично, во всяком случае у меня на ноутбуке которому...уже лет 5 наверное отработало без проблем

Comment: @FoggyFinder как я понял, алгоритм следующий:
1) Берем 1 вектор, вычисляем расстояния от него до 2 вектора, 3, ..., n. Если оно меньше заданной нами величины smallDecimal, то удаляем 1 вектор из списка векторов.
2) Берем 2 вектор, вычисляем расстояния от него до 3, 4, ... n. и т.д.

И разве это не займет больших затрат по времени? Наверно, я не так что-то понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/),
тогда надо установить nuget пакет `Install-Package WriteableBitmapEx`.

В XAML добавить

```
<Image x:Name="image" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Тогда в вашем методе `button_Click()` после получения векторов нужно изменить на следующее

```
//создаем экземпляр для рисования шириной 1000 и высотой 500
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = BitmapFactory.New(1000, 500);
//присваиваем в качестве картинки для отображения
this.image.Source = writeableBmp;

//рисуем
foreach (var vector in vectors)
{
    DrawEllipse(writeableBmp, vector);
}
```

И метод рисования эллипса такой

```
/// <summary>
/// Рисование эллипса
/// </summary>
/// <param name="writeableBmp">экземпляр битмапа</param>
/// <param name="vector">отображаемый вектор</param>
private void DrawEllipse(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp, Vector vector)
{
    int thickness = 2; //толщина контура
    int width = 4;
    int height = 4;

    //рисуем основной контур
    writeableBmp.DrawEllipseCentered(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1],
                                                                      width, height, Colors.Black);

    //рисуем дополнительные контуры для толщины
    for (int i = 0; i < thickness; i++)
    {
        writeableBmp.DrawEllipseCentered(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1],
                                                                      width++, height++, Colors.Black);
    }

    //заполняем цветом
    writeableBmp.FillEllipseCentered(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1],
                                                                 width-thickness, height-thickness, Colors.Yellow);
}
```

Рисование по вашему примеру на моем компе занимало порядка 25 сек. С использованием этой библиотеки стало около 16 сек. Попробуйте, может лучше станет :) Честно я ожидал большего, когда читал англ. SO. Но имеем то, что имеем.

**P.S. изменения после комментария**
Да, можно добавить необходимой асинхронности, тогда работа будет выглядеть более осмысленно, вот так:

[image: пример асинхронной работы]

Измените метод `DrawEllipse` вот так

```
private void DrawEllipse(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp, Vector vector)
{
    int thickness = 2; //толщина контура
    int width = 4;
    int height = 4;

    //рисуем основной контур
    Action action = () => writeableBmp.DrawEllipseCentered(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1],
                                                                      width, height, Colors.Black);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);

    //рисуем дополнительные контуры для толщины
    for (int i = 0; i < thickness; i++)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            writeableBmp.DrawEllipseCentered(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1],
                                                                      width++, height++, Colors.Black);
        }));
    }

    //заполняем цветом
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        writeableBmp.FillEllipseCentered(vector.Coordinates[0], vector.Coordinates[1],
                                                                 width - thickness, height - thickness, Colors.Yellow);
    }));
}
```

Разместите в окне `TextBlock`, на который мы будет выводить номера нарисованных эллипсов. В дескриптор метода `button_Click()` добавьте `async`.
Тогда рисовать можно двумя способами:

```
//рисуем Cпособ I
int showNum = 0;
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    foreach (var vector in vectors)
    {
        //выводим номер вектора
        Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate { this.textBlock.Text = showNum.ToString(); });
        //увеличиваем счетчик
        showNum++;
        //асинхронная отрисовка
        await Task.Run(() => DrawEllipse(writeableBmp, vector));
        //задержка чтоб успело отобразиться
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
});
```

Другой способ через деление на порции

```
//рисуем Cпособ II
int take = 100; //размер порции
for (int skip = 0; skip < vectorsCount; skip += take)
{
    //берем порцию
    var partVectors = vectors.Skip(skip).Take(take);
    //сообщаем (отсчет будет порциями, хотя реально будет нарисовано меньше)
    this.textBlock.Text = skip.ToString();

    //формируем коллекцию задач
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var vector in partVectors)
    {
        tasks.Add(new Task(() =>
        {
            DrawEllipse(writeableBmp, vector);
        }));
    }
    //стартуем все задачи порции
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.Start();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
    //дождаться завершения всех задач порции
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Визуально выглядит лучше, но скорости это не добавляет.:)

Comment: Спасибо! Я обязательно попробую этот метод и отпишу сюда.

Comment: Попробовал данный метод - неплохо, но до желаемого результата, увы, далеко. Может быть, вы знаете, как отрисовывать фигуры на нажатие кнопки таким образом, чтобы они отобразились не все сразу, а по несколько тысяч в секунду? Как правильно называется метод, который "обновляет" полотно рисования, чтобы можно было его обновлять несколько раз за цикл?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ловите варианты с асинхронностью.

Comment: интересная реализация! :) Да, скорости, увы, не добавится, но зато пользователю хоть не скучно)