# Оптимизация выборки из списка

Tags: c#, алгоритм, list, linq

Всем доброе время суток! У меня есть список LIST, где хранятся значения координат. Также у меня есть участок, например 2000м на 2000м, который разбили на более мелкие участки (25 на 25 метров). Из этого исходя у меня есть сетка 80 на 80, куда мне ну;yj разместить точки из списка и подсчитать, сколько этих точек находится на каждом из этих маленьких участков (который 25 на 25 метров)

Я сделал следующий алгоритм, но на таких объемах, какие я указал в примере, программа тратит кучу времени и ресурсов для выполнения этих действий. Точек в списке примерно 400-600:

```
            for (int i = 0, i1 = 0; i < 2000 && i1 < 80; i = i + 25, i1 += 1)
            {
                for (int j = 0, j1 = 0; j < 2000 && j1 < 80; j = j + 25, j1 += 1)
                {
                   //CountSelectedPointsInBin список координат
                   // выполняю linq запрос по расчету суммы точек на нужном маленьком участке
                    int multip = CountSelectedPointsInBin.Where(p => p.PointX >= i && p.PointX <= i + SizeBinX && p.PointY >= j && p.PointY <= j + SizeBinY).Sum(p => p.NumRect);
                    // загоняю все в массив
                    arrayBin[i1, j1] = multip;
                }
```

Как можно оптимизировать этот код?? Или вообще сделать по другому, чтобы программа быстрее выполняла такие не сложные операции?

```
   public static List<PointsSelectedObjects> CountSelectedPointsInBin
    {
        get
        {
            if (selectedPointsInBin.Count != 0) return countSelectedPointsInBin;
            else return null;
        }
    }

    public static void CountintsInBin()
    {
        countSelectedPointsInBin = new List<PointsSelectedObjects>();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedPointsInBin.Count; i++)
        {
            double coordX = 0, coordY = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < selectedPointsInBin.Count; j++)
            {
                if (selectedPointsInBin[i].PointX == selectedPointsInBin[j].PointX && selectedPointsInBin[i].PointY == selectedPointsInBin[j].PointY)
                {
                    countPoints++;
                    coordX = selectedPointsInBin[i].PointX;
                    coordY = selectedPointsInBin[i].PointY;
                }
            }
            PointsSelectedObjects points = new PointsSelectedObjects(coordX, coordY, countPoints);
            countSelectedPointsInBin.Add(points);
            countPoints = 0;
        }
    }
```

Его я вызываю на форме и он подсчитывается нормально.

Вот класс этих координат:

```
public class PointsSelectedObjects
{
    double pointX;
    double pointY;
    int numRect;
    int countPoints;
    public PointsSelectedObjects(double x, double y, int countPoints, bool point = false)
    {
        pointX = x;
        pointY = y;
        this.countPoints = countPoints;
    }
```

И там еще есть public свойства этих перемен (get и set)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос объявление переменной `CountSelectedPointsInBin` и объявление класса того, что помещается в список.

Comment: Чему равны переменные `SizeBinY`, `SizeBinX` ?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko добавил код класс и списка

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk они равняются 25 метров по оси Х и по оси У. Это размеры мелкого участка, они просто заведены в переменные были и тут забыл их расшифровать

Comment: Какой размер у списка `CountSelectedPointsInBin` в данном примере?  Я вижу. что он размера `selectedPointsInBin.Count`,  но я не знаю, какого размера этот список)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko там все списки не очень большие от 200-600 где-то, варьируются в этом диапозоне

Comment: @АлександрМустафин Я сейчас попробую одну оптимизацию. Если получится - напишу ответ. Только скажите: какое примерно время затрачивается на эти вычисления у Вас?

Comment: @АлександрМустафин вы знаете, ваш цикл у меня выполняется за 1-5 миллисекунд. Знаете, проблема может быть не в этом цикле, а в отображении на форме ваших 2000 точек (или других объектов, которые отображаются и которых много). Формы очень долго отображают большое количество объектов.

Comment: @АлександрМустафин Вот [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635436/wpf-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80). У меня тоже была работа с большим количеством точек. И дело оказалось в их отображении на форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` - ваш массив с точками.
`arr` - массив полей. Значение — количество попаданий

```
var arr = new int[80, 80];
list.ForEach(t => arr[(int)(t.X / 25), (int)(t.Y / 25)]++);
```

Время выполнения: O(n).